# Stop App from Registering in the Share Menu

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to exclude my app from appearing in Android share menu. My app is not designed to handle images, yet when the user select an image from gallery and then select share my app appears. How can I filter my app out. Here is the Intent Filter

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.domainname.myactivity"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

Comment: Please post your entire manifest. A "share menu" is driven usually by `ACTION_SEND` `Intents`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it was the ACTION_SEND that I needed to filter for for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note: In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare it in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your activity.

When specifying the SEND action in your intent filter, don't include DEFAULT category:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

     <!-- Drop this line, it allows you to receive implicit intents-->
     <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>-->
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks @inner_class7 , that helps however I had to apply that to the ACTION_SEND intent filter.

Comment: @ValOkafor of course, this code was never shared so i overlooked that part, im updating my answer to reflect the correct action